# Is there a way to comment out select lines of code in a block of VB code?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm working in a Visual Basic file and want to comment out specific lines of code in a large block of code that declares a string variable. However, I find that whenever I comment out any lines of code in the middle of the code block, I get the following errors:

- at the end of the preceeding line (above) i get "BC30201: Expression Expected"
- at the start of the subsequent line (below) i get "BC30035: Syntax error"

Is it not possible to comment out individual lines of code in a larger code block in Visual Basic?

Here is a simple example:

```
Dim someVariable = "this is the first line of a story..." & vbCrLf &
"this is the second line of a story..." & vbCrLf &
'"this is the third line, option 1, of a story..." & vbCrLf &
"this is the third line, option 2, of a story..." & vbCrLf &
"this is the fourth line of a story..."
```

In the above block, I'd like to run the code with third line commented out. Then maybe later I may want to run the code with the third line commented back in and with the fourth line commented out. Is that possible?

I apologize for what I imagine is a pretty obvious question, but I have not been able to get an answer or alternative solution from my research.

I tried commenting out each individual line of code, but get the same error messages. I could not find an alternative way to accomplish this on the internet, but I also am not finding any evidence that what I am trying to do is impossible in Visual Basic either.

Comment: Guessing your error comes from trailing "&" without a follow up string to connect it too. Before you go farther I'd suggest putting the strings into an array. That would allow you to pick which one to use based on the situation.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. the motivation for my question was to see if there were syntactically convenient ways to comment out lines of code when i'm messing around or investigating issues (not really looking at refactoring at this point). based another user's response, it seems it's just not possible to do this in VB in the same ways you can in other main stream languages like Java, C# or JS.

Comment: There is a peculiar quirk that you are allowed to have a comment AFTER the final ampersand on a line. So you could remove the linefeed before the quote character.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, until you add the comment, all that code is technically *one line*. What VB.Net is doing to allow it work across multiple real lines is called **implicit line continuation**. That is, it continues the prior line from where the previous left off.

That's fine for most code, but when you add the comment the thing to understand is it's still part of the continued code line.

This creates two problems:

1. The prior real line on the screen ended with a binary operator (`&`), but now everything on the next real line is commented out, allowing the code line to end, but with nothing completing the required right-hand side argument for the operator.
2. The code line now beginning after the comment resolves to a string expression *that doesn't do anything*: it's not assigned anywhere, and no methods are called. That's not legal either.

The fix is in two parts. First, *you don't need all those concatenation operators or `vbCrLf` constants at all*. VB.Net has multi-line string literals now, and will do that for you automatically.

Second, you can comment out the *whole variable assignment* for each option:

```vb
'Dim someVariable As String = "this is the first line of a story...
'this is the second line of a story...
'this is the third line, option 1, of a story...
'this is the fourth line of a story..."


Dim someVariable As String = "this is the first line of a story...
this is the second line of a story...
this is the third line, option 2, of a story...
this is the fourth line of a story..."
```

If that seems cumbersome, you have options.

One is the Visual Studio keyboard shortcuts for inserting or removing comment characters, which will let you select a block of text and act on it with one command. Another option is using different variable names, and selecting which variable you want later, so the correct variable assignment is still just a one-line change. A third option is building up the string based on conditional expressions in the code.

My preference is towards one of the latter options, as it helps me trend towards data-driven or more-flexible code down the line.

Comment: thanks for your response. i guess i ultimately can't comment out individual lines of code in a block as we can in other languages like Java, C# or JS. bummer, but it's good to have confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1 - remove linefeed**

There is a quirk in VB.NET that allows a comment to appear after the final ampersand on a line. So you could move the commented-out line to the end of the previous line:

```
Dim someVariable = "this is the first line of a story..." & vbCrLf &
"this is the second line of a story..." & vbCrLf & '"this is the third line, option 1, of a story..." & vbCrLf &
"this is the third line, option 2, of a story..." & vbCrLf &
"this is the fourth line of a story..."
```

**Option 2 - use StringBuilder**

Because strings are immutable in .NET, it is technically more efficient to use the `StringBuilder` class to concatenate strings. If you do so, you get the bonus that each line is a separate line of code and can be commented-out easily:

```
Dim sb = New StringBuilder
sb.AppendLine("this is the first line of a story...")
sb.AppendLine("this is the second line of a story...")
'sb.AppendLine("this is the third line, option 1, of a story...")
sb.AppendLine("this is the third line, option 2, of a story...")
sb.AppendLine("this is the fourth line of a story...")
someVariable = sb.ToString()
```

Comment: oh that quirk having the comment in the same line is actually useful and seems to be what i was looking for - thank you! duly noted on strings and the stringbuilder. my question is motivated by convenience in removing lines of code for dev testing and troubleshooting, and not something i'd ever check in.